# How I can automatically reload a webview after have recovered the internet connection?

Tags: android, webview, broadcastreceiver

how I can automatically reload a webview after have recovered the internet connection? I am using a brodcastreceiver to know when is connected or not, but i dont know how to put the code into the BroadcastReceiver to reload the webview. Sorry for my bad english.
Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    static WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StrictMode.enableDefaults();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com.ar");

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() );

    }

    public class ConnectionBroadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)    
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            // HERE I WANT TO RELOAD MY WEBVIEW
            } else {
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code you have already tried and maybe somebody will help you

Comment: Ok, thanks! I put the code :).

Answer (score 0):

You can reload your webview via

```
mWebview.reload();
```